# Send data from PC to Raspberry

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, uart

I'm wondering if I can do something like this:
Do some image processing with opencv on my pc, do some math and send data to RaspberyPi to PID controller and then control servos, in real time.

UART wolud be the best connection?

Comment: RaspberryPi is a computer and PC is another one. And you wonder how they can communicate with each other? Are you going to use the ethernet port for something else? Or how about wireless?

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can use any means to communicate from the PC to the Raspberry PI that are available (UART, ethernet, etc.).

However, you just have to be careful about any time requirements you have in the system you are controlling and check whether the communication rate is suitable.

For instance, you can use 9600 baud UART to temperature control, as the dynamics of such systems are usually slow. If your servos control an inverted pendulum, then the communication speed might make it impossible to control.